# Mapping of Product items to an order using a Map<Product, Integer>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 tables:

- Stock (StockID, AvailableQty)
- Customers(CustomerID, Name)
- Orders (OrderID, CustomerID)
- OrderDetails (OrderDetailsID, OrderID, StockID, Quantity)

A customer can have many orders, and an order consists of many orderDetails items.
I'm trying to store the stock items in map that consists of the StockItem and a Integer being the quantity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "OrderID"))
public class OrderEntity extends IdentifiableEntity {

    @OneToOne //Not sure if it is one to one?
    @JoinColumn(name = "CustomerID")
    private CustomerEntity customer;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "OrderDetails", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "StockID"))
    @Column(name = "Quantity")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "OrderID")
    private Map<StockEntity, Integer> orderItems;

}
```

When I try to persist it this way, the first stock item is added to the the OrderDetails table with the orderID of 1. But the next one is inserted using the orderID of 2 (which doesn't exist).

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, and I think it works, but I'll be lying if I understood why it works

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "OrderDetails", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "OrderID", referencedColumnName = "OrderID")})
    @Column(name = "Quantity")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "StockReferenceID")
    private Map<StockEntity, Integer> orderItems;
```

Comment: MapKeyJoinColumn is to define the column used to store the key - the StockEntity ID in this case. It was always getting set from the value from the referenced StockEntity instances; You incorrectly mapped it the first time around to populate the orderID FK column with those values instead of the StockReferenceID FK, so it got values 1, 2 etc. The insert would have included consistent values for the "StockID" column, which were pulled from the referencing OrderEntity instance (pulling the value from it's "OrderID" by default) . You've now got it mapped to go into a OrderID column correctly.